# How to generate thumbnail from a uploaded video using Imagine’s library

Tags: php, symfony, thumbnails, php-imagine

How to generate thumbnail from  a uploaded video using Imagine’s library.
i want to generate thumb when i upload a video from backend. i m using sonata media bundle. they are using imagine library from generating thumbnails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do that, you need to use any video conversion library, it will help to generate image from video file.

Link: [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/)